# gtest - why does one test affect behavior of other?

Tags: googletest

Currently I have a gtest which has a gtest object with some member variables and functions.

I have a simple test, as well as more complex tests later on. If I comment out the complex tests, my simple test runs perfectly fine. However, when I include the other tests (even though I'm using gtest_filter to only run the first test), I start getting segfaults. I know it's impossible to debug without posting my code, but I guess I wanted to know more at a high level how this could occur. My understanding is that TEST_F constructs/destructs a new object every time it is run, so how could it be possible that the existence of a test affects another? Especially if I'm filtering, shouldn't the behavior be exactly the same?

Comment: Global state would be the most obvious cause.

Comment: @DaisyShipton thank you for your quick response. Do global states persist within the test object? Right now the only variables I have globally are static consts, and everything else is within the test object.

Comment: That sounds like it *should* be okay. (Not that I've done much C++ testing, to be honest. It was more of a general though.) Are you able to run the tests in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

TEST_F does not construct/destruct a new "object" ( at this point I assume that object here is to be interpreted as instance of the feature test class)   for each test

What is done before each test of the test feature is to call the SetUp method and after each test the TearDown method is called.
Test feature constructor and destructor are called only once.

But because you did not provide a mvce , we can not assume further

Comment: As of 2021 for gtest 1.8.0:  Please see https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/tags/release-1.8.0/googletest/docs/FAQ.md . Here is what is says:" Google Test does not reuse the same test fixture object across multiple tests. For each TEST_F, Google Test will create a fresh test fixture object, immediately call SetUp(), run the test body, call TearDown(), and then immediately delete the test fixture object.
When you need to write per-test set-up and tear-down logic, you have the choice between using fixture constructor/destructor or SetUp()/TearDown(). "